# Change look and feel of Spinner View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I need to change the look and feel of the Spinner View, so the little triangle in the lower right part is a bit bigger, and with a circular shape in his "back".

I've been looking but all the tutorials refer to the custom adapter part of customizing a Spinner.

Anybody knows some tutorial to look at to change the appearance of a View?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to build a custom view:

1- By extending the view 
2- Compound many views 
3- Create a totally new one

Here an example: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: Yeah, i know that...I don't need to change the way it behaves, only the way it looks.

Comment: Maybe you can just change the background of the spinner as follows:<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/my_prompt" 
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    />

Comment: Finally did it by setting as drawable an xml as a selector, and inside it defining which images should be used in every state of the Spinner, but you put me in the right track, so...thank you :)